# Vue.js. Отображение блока с текстом, если ul не содержит в себе li-элементов

Tags: javascript, vue.js

друзья. 
Разработкой занимаюсь полтора месяца, на вью около 2 недель, поэтому строго не судите пожалуйста, если вопрос составлен не совсем корректно

li у меня добавляется динамически с помощью функции, прописанной для этого. Также по клику li можно удалить.
Задумка такая: когда ul не содержит в себе li, отображается блок с надписью "СПИСОК ДЕЛ ПУСТ". Как только добавляется li - надпись исчезает. 
Помогите пожалуйста, как можно грамотно реализовать подобное? 
Пробовала с помощью template v-if / template v-else - но видимо написала какую-то шнягу, не получилось

Comment: `template v-if / template v-else` вполне подходит для этого. Покажите "шнягу" , которую вы написали

Comment: решила проблему просто с v-if / v-else и без проверки ul на наличие li, нашла способ для моей проблемы в разы проще, спасибо) Тот код с template не сохранился. Нет привычки оставлять код, который не сработал. С template позже попробовала еще раз и все получилось) Некорректно прописала условие изначально

Answer (score 1):

```
<template v-if="tasks.length === 0"> 
 Список дел пуст
</template>
```

Логика простая, содержимое отображается в том случае, если в массиве `tasks` содержится 0 элементов.
Стоит уточнить, что я использовал `template` только для примера, вместо него может быть любой тег, например: `<span>`, `<div>`, `<h1>`, `<h2>` и т.д.

Так же в `Vue` есть `v-show`. Разница между `v-if` и `v-show` заключается в том, что `v-if` убирает элемент из DOM, а `v-show` скрывает его через CSS (элемент остается в DOM). Так же стоит отметить, что `v-show` не работает с `v-else`. В данном случае использование `v-if`, на мой взгляд, более уместно, т.к. переключения будут редкими, но такой вариант тоже есть.

Более подробно можно узнать в документации - [Vue.JS: Условная отрисовка](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)